# Drawing a NSImage into NSView subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawing, nsview

Here's my code so far (in the draw rect):

```
// Drawing code here.
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NoiseBGMainView" ofType:@"jpg"]);
NSURL *pathToBGImage = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NoiseBGMainView" ofType:@"jpg"]];
NSImage *NoiseBGMainView = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathToBGImage];
[NoiseBGMainView drawInRect:[self bounds] fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];
```

And the image doesn't draw... I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Have you proven that `noiseBGMainView` is not `nil`?

Comment: NSLog it, the same way you did the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `[NSImage imageNamed:@"NoiseBGMainView.jpg"]` instead?  That will give you an `NSImage` of your picture (if it can find it), and `nil` if it can't.  `NSLog` what the results of that call are, then come and report back on whether it's logging `(null)` or not.

Comment: The path is all fine, its the drawing that is the problem

Comment: Was just going to answer this. +1

Comment: Well, even if the path is ok, using `imageNamed:` is better because the code you show is leaking an NSURL and NSImage each time it runs.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that it's not good practice to name instances with an initial capital letter. The image variable should be named `noiseBGMainView` or preferably `noiseBGMainImage` since it's an image, not a view. See http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/

Answer (score 1):

You can draw an NSImage into an NSView without writing any drawing code by attaching an [NSImageView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your view and setting your image resource as the NSImageView's image. (NSImageView handles all the drawing).

If your custom NSView is loaded from a nib, you don't need any setup code either - just make the appropriate NSView-NSImageView-NSImage (resource) connections with Interface Builder.

Comment: I Have this, and this doesn't work: 
   `NSImage *noiseBGMainView = [NSImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NoiseBGMainView" ofType:@"jpg"]];
 NSLog(@"%@", noiseBGMainView);
 NSImageView *bgImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
 [bgImageView setImage:noiseBGMainView];
 [self addSubview:bgImageView];`
Any Idea What's Wrong?

Comment: If you set up NSImageView programmatically (instead of with IB), you'll need to give it a nonzero frame.

Try changing:

NSImageView *bgImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];

to:

NSImageView *bgImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(0,0,100,100)];

Comment: Works great, but I need the image to repeat?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *pathToBGImage = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NoiseBGMainView" ofType:@"jpg"]];
```

This is wrong. `-[NSURL initWithString:]` takes a string version of a URL, such as http://apple.com/, not a pathname.

Because you didn't pass a URL, the URL will be a relative URL, but a relative URL needs a base. The URL is a valid object, but doesn't lead anywhere. This, in turn, causes `initWithContentsOfURL:` to return `nil` (because you tried to load an image from a relative URL with no base). You then try to tell the image to draw, but you don't have an image, so nothing happens.

You want `initFileURLWithPath:`. (Or the class method `fileURLWithPath:`, with which you won't have to release the URL later.)